# Adding function dropdown on desired page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've made a function which should on theory change the displayed number of products in Woocommerce dropdown. The function is from another thread here.

My question is how to show the dropdown on the page on which I want to be visible?

This is the function

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'ps_selectbox', 25 );
function ps_selectbox() {
    $per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);     
    echo '<div class="dropdown2">';
    echo '<button onclick="myPage()" class="dropbtn">Per page </button>';
    echo '<div id="myPage" class="dropdown-content">';
    $orderby_options = array(
        '15' => '15',
        '20' => '20',
        '50' => '50',
        '75' => '75',
        '150' => '150',
        '200' => '200'
    );
    foreach( $orderby_options as $value => $label ) {
        echo "<a ".selected( $per_page, $value )." onchange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value" value='?perpage=$value'>$label</a>";
    }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ps_pre_get_products_query' );
function ps_pre_get_products_query( $query ) {
    $per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    if( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() && is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $per_page );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!function_exists('ps_selectbox')){
    function ps_selectbox() {
        $per_page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'perpage', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);     
        echo '<div class="dropdown2">';
        echo '<button onclick="myPage()" class="dropbtn">Per page </button>';
        echo '<div id="myPage" class="dropdown-content">';
        $orderby_options = array(
            '15' => '15',
            '20' => '20',
            '50' => '50',
            '75' => '75',
            '150' => '150',
            '200' => '200'
        );
        foreach( $orderby_options as $value => $label ) {
            echo "<a ".selected( $per_page, $value )." onchange='if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value' value='?perpage=$value'>$label</a>";
        }
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
```

Add this in functions.php and call the function ps_selectbox()

```
function render_ps_selectbox() {
    return ps_selectbox();
}
add_shortcode( 'ps_selectbox', 'render_ps_selectbox' );
```

Use [ps_selectbox] in page builder

Comment: Thanks but have question. How exactly I can call `ps_selectbox()` in the theme builder? I've tried with `raw HTML` box but I see `ps_selectbox()` as a text because currently I have access to the Admin Dashboard only

Comment: @Ivanov Updated answer

Comment: Hm, something is not right. When I'm in category of products e.g. `http://example.com/products/?countries=usa` the dropdown shows as options all categories instead of `15`, `20`,...etc. It is printing `http://example.com/products/?product_cat=carpets`. Very strange.